# While comparing a date inside a file with the system date getting the error : line 7: 10#2020-12-09: value too great for base (error token is "09")

Tags: linux, octal

```
 #!/bin/bash
docker logs <container_name> | grep 'expiration date of' | tail -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 14 | cut -c 2-11 > /tmp/dt

dateFile=`cat /tmp/dt`

NOW=$( date +%F )

 if [ $((10#$dateFile)) -gt ${NOW} ]; then
   echo No Renewal Required
else
   echo Renewal Required
fi
```

I am getting the date from a file and sending that value into another file /tmp/dt.Then comparing that date with the system date to create logic.but getting the error : line 7: 10#2020-12-09: value too great for base (error token is "09"). also I am using #10 to nullify the octal error.

Answer (score 0):

`-gt` compares numbers, which means integers in bash. Bash interprets both the operands as arithmetic expressions, and yours is parsed as

```
10#2020 - 12 - 09
```

So, it starts with 2020 in decimal, subtracts 12, and tries to subtract 09: the initial 0 tells it to interpret the number in octal, but 9 can't appear in octal numbers, hence the error.

Dates in the YYYY-MM-DD format can be compared as strings. Use

```
[ "$dateFile" > "$NOW" ]
```

Comment: @abhirupghosh: "thanks" on StackOverflow = upvote / accept.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
docker logs <container name> | grep 'expiration date of' | tail -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 14 | cut -c 2-11 > /tmp/dt
dateFile=`cat /tmp/dt`
NOW=$( date +%F )
 if [ "$NOW" > "$dateFile" ]; then
   echo No Renewal Required
else
   echo Renewal Required
fi

just to test, i reverse the logic but it still shows "No Renewal Required " where my system date($now) is not gretter (>) than $dateFile..so it should be "Renewal Required ". any idea where is the error.